# Docker compose stand on "attaching to Traefik"

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, vps, traefik

I try to do this [Home Media Server](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-reverse-proxy-tutorial-for-docker/) using Debian.

Here is my [docker-compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/cWtctx16)

And here is my [traefik.toml](https://pastebin.com/mVijLibK)

I don't understand why when I launch `docker-compose -f ${USERDIR}/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d`  and use `docker-compose logs -tf --tail="50" traefik` to watch if everything is ok it stand on `Attaching to traefik`

I except this to happen :

[image: IT WORKS]

Also I should have access to my traefik dashboard using traefik.domain.com but it didn't work :

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Here is also my DNS on CloudFlare :

[image: DNS on CloudFlare]

I don't know what else I can do to make it works. Thanks you !

Comment: Do you already tried to nslookup your domain?

Comment: I tried, the answer I got is : server 127.0.0.53 and the non-authoritative answer is my domain and my server public ip

Comment: hmm... then you tried to open with Google Chrome? How about incognito mode? It could be DNS cache messed up with chrome :/